# Unix shell scripting need to count the files

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to write a shell script to count the number of files in daywise directory and compare it with the archive area daywise directory can any one help me I am new to shell scripting

Comment: Please update your post along with your research. Show us what you have did so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to compare. But count the files in a folder could be done like this

```
ls -l daywise | wc -l
```

And you can assign the num to a variable like this

```
daywise_file_count=$(ls -l daywise | wc -l)
```

As the same, you can get archive daywise file count too just as above.

Comment: This won't count files starting with a dot and will count non regular files. Thinking about down-voting...

Comment: I would like to call it from different directory and I need to count .mhs format files

Comment: I think you should give an example to explain what you ask.

Comment: For example I will get files(number may differ per day) in today's date folder and it will get processed and goes to archive folder I should count how many files I got and how many I processed